# How to browse loaded assemblies, components during runtime in VB6?

Tags: vb6, assemblies, components

Is there any way to browse a list loaded assemblies, components using VB6 development environment(Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0) during runtime? I have application on VB6 and want to know which assemblies are loaded when I make some actions. In VS2008 there is "Modules" window which show such info, need to know the same info in VB6.

If it is possible to get such info using VB6 code, this should be good too

Thanks in advance,
Vasyl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) 2.x.

You can set it for profiling which will watch a running application and report on the loaded modules.

[This article](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/application_profiling.htm) has more information on DW's profiling feature.

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe take a look at the Object Browser (F2) and the Call Stack (while debugging code.. View/Call Stack) on the menu bar..